# How to open view with each image on openFlow api, in the ipad?

Tags: iphone, ipad, coverflow

i follow the instruction of this tutorial

[how to add coverflow effect on your iphone app openflow](http://blog.objectgraph.com/index.php/2010/04/09/how-to-add-coverflow-effect-on-your-iphone-app-openflow/)

i used the last version of openFlow(http://github.com/tupps/OpenFlow) and works great, but What I need is make each image as button or menu and when i click it, this will open another view, but so far I can't do that .

Any clues  or tips to implement this feature ?

Thanks